# Convertir texto en array PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un texto que tiene este formato:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "creado_por":"superadmin",
  "fecha_y_hora_de_creacion":"2018-06-09 11:04:08",
  "auditor_asignado":"Yheferzon",
  "nombre_beneficiario":"CHARLES XAVIER"
}
```

Y no he podido convertirlo en un array para poder trabajar con el, alguna manito se los agradezco.

Comment: Puedes poner el código de lo que has intentado ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esa cadena tiene formato **JSON**, por lo tanto, si tienes ese texto en una variable, puedes usar json_decode.  El segundo parametro, **TRUE**, significa que quieres que te devuelva un array associativo.  Prueba este codigo:

```
<?php
$text = '{
  "id":"1",
  "creado_por":"superadmin",
  "fecha_y_hora_de_creacion":"2018-06-09 11:04:08",
  "auditor_asignado":"Yheferzon",
  "nombre_beneficiario":"CHARLES XAVIER"
}';

$array = json_decode($text, TRUE);

echo $array['id'];

?>
```

Comment: solo faltaba el TRUE, ahora si es un array, gracias!!!!!

Comment: Sería bueno, en este tipo de respuestas, agregar una pequeña nota conceptual como: No se trataba de una cadena cualquiera. **Tiene el formato típico de un objeto json** y por ello se usa json_decode() y quizás algo adicional acerca del parámetro TRUE usado.

Comment: ya edite mi respuesta